# Why do I get undefined for application.android.context in nativescript-angular app?

Tags: android, angular, clipboard, nativescript

I'm getting the following error while trying to use the nativescript-clipboard plugin within a nativescript-angular app.
Because I'm new to nativescript I'm most likely doing something wrong.

This is the complete error:

> Error in clipboard.setText: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'getSystemService' of undefined
>   (/home/linuxtest/sample-ng-todomvc/node_modules/nativescript-clipboard/clipboard.android.js:13:15)
>   I'm

currently have version 1.1.3 of the plugin.

And here is the section where I'm trying to use your plugin

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
var clipboardModule = require("nativescript-clipboard");


@Component({
    selector: "my-clipboard",
    templateUrl: "templates/my-clipboard.html"
})
export class MyClipboard {
    greeting:string;
    constructor(){
        this.greeting = "Hello Github!";
    }

    save(text) {
        clipboardModule.setText(text).then(()=>{
            console.log(texto + ", copied to clipboard");
        });
    }

    read() {
        clipboardModule.getText().then((content)=>{
            console.log("Read from clipboard: " + content);
        });
    }
}
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have logged the solution in the issue you have opened in the authors repository but in order for the community to get the answer will post a link here as well.
[Solution to this problem in the authors repository](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-clipboard/issues/2)

Comment: Well, thank you very much! I managed to take it a little further and define the reference to your library as a class attribute instead of doing it twice.